# method to receive wholesale cost and markup % as arguments and return retail price c#

Tags: c#, methods

I typed out this code for homework and it works. However, the method part is incorrect. The method should receive 2 values (wholesale price and markup percentage) from the form as arguments and return the retail price. Here is what I have so far, and I am just wondering what I need to move where to get the method correct.

```
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void CalculateRetail()//method header
     {//method body
        decimal Cost, //variables
                Percent,
                Perc,
                PercAmt,
                FinCost;

        Cost = Convert.ToDecimal(txtCost.Text);
        Percent = Convert.ToDecimal(txtPercent.Text);

        Perc = (Percent / 100);
        PercAmt = Cost * Perc;
        FinCost = Cost + PercAmt;

        lblFinCost.Text = "The Retail Price with markup is " + FinCost.ToString("C2"); //output to label
    }//end method body
    private void btnCalc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        decimal Cost;
        decimal Percent;

        lblFinCost.Text = "";

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtCost.Text)) // input validation check to make sure not blank
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number for the cost", "Error");
            return;
        } //end if

        if (!decimal.TryParse(txtCost.Text, out Cost)) // input validation check to make sure is whole number
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number for the cost", "Error");
            return;
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPercent.Text)) // input validation check to make sure not blank
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number for the cost", "Error");
            return;
        } //end if

        if (!decimal.TryParse(txtPercent.Text, out Percent)) // input validation check to make sure is whole number
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number for the cost", "Error");
            return;
        }
        CalculateRetail(); //call method once error check passes
    }

    private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtCost.Text = "";//clear form
        txtPercent.Text = "";
        lblFinCost.Text = "";

    }

    private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close(); //close form
    }
```

Comment: Rewrite your method to take two arguments, perhaps?  I.e., `private void CalculateRetail(decimal price, decimal markup)`

Comment: It works as intended, but I was informed I had too much under the method header that I need to move the body as part of the button click event and only call the method after the error checking.

Comment: Basically your asking for a code review. There's a site for that: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I didn't think I needed the code reviewed. Thanks for down-voting though.

Comment: @venerik CodeReview needs working code, that means the code needs to produce the expected results so this is off topic on CodeReview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that you show the same error when checking if a field is empty or cannot be converted to a decimal, combine the two:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtCost.Text) || !decimal.TryParse(txtCost.Text, out cost))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number for the cost", "Error");
    return;
}
```

(Same for txtPercent.)

Your main problem is that you don't use parameters. Your method can be rewritten like this:

```
private void CalculateRetail(decimal cost, decimal percent)
{
    var percAmt = Cost * (percent / 100);
    var finCost = cost + percAmt;

    lblFinCost.Text = "The Retail Price with markup is " + finCost.ToString("C2");
}
```

And then called like this:

```
CalculateRetail(cost, percent);
```

Note that local variables should be CamelCase, not PascalCase, i.e. they shouldn't start with a capital.

Also avoid comments that only describe what we already can see; these only clutter your code:

```
//end method body
//output to label
//variables
```

Variable names like `finCost` and `percAmt` are bad, by the way. There's no penalty for using proper descriptive names; the next person to come along will have it much easier to maintain your code if he or she doesn't have to figure out first what a variable contains.

Comment: Thanks worked like a charm. The cleaning up of the error checking and the CamelCase helps. I appreciate the constructive criticism. :)